# generator to list conversion yields different results when it is done in or outside the a list comprehension

Tags: python, numpy, generator, list-comprehension

I had a code snippet behaving weirdly; I made another to illustrate the problem.  I think the two snippets should yield identical results but don't :

```
alphas = np.arange(5)
args = zip(np.arange(5), np.arange(5))

output = [np.mean([ a+b for a, b in args]) for _ in alphas]
```

yielding

```
[4.0, nan, nan, nan, nan]
```

and

```
alphas = np.arange(5)
args = zip(np.arange(5), np.arange(5))
args = list(args)  # <- this is the only difference

output = [np.mean([ a+b for a, b in args]) for _ in alphas]
```

yielding

```
[4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0]
```

The only difference is that the generator is converted to a list inside the list comprehension.
Does anyone understand the underlying mechanism that makes the results different ?

Comment: Fixed the outputs for you.

Comment: `zip` returns an iterator, and you're trying to iterate over it multiple times (once for each `_ in alphas`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for your edit. Sorry for swapping the outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A generator produces the output sequence only once.  Your first expression uses the entire sequence on the out `for`'s first iteration.  When `_` advances from 0 to 1 and cycles around to iterate through `args` again, there's nothing left to `yield`, and you have an empty return.  This results in `nan` for the `mean` value.

In your second example, `args` is a static list; you can iterate through that as many times as you like.

Comment: Oh I see ! Thank you for the explanation :)

Comment: And thank you for the edit. I apologize for the mistakes I made.